# Как получить значение атрибута value у элемента input строкой

Tags: python, html, selenium, pytest, value

При написании автотестов на python/selenium для сравнения в итоговом assert возникает необходимость получить значение атрибута value введенное в инпуте, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогла команда: `.get_attribute('value')`.

Пример для использования:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"пароль").get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: Нужно подучить JS, Вы можете такое реализовать с помощью `execute_script`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но причем тут execute_script если у меня элемент в видимой области?

Comment: потому что с инпута насколько мне известно нельзя вытаскивать строки, и не всегда эта строка имеется в дереве элементов. Скажем есть условный фреймворк, есть условный бэк который подтягивает данные с базы в строку input, и в дереве это будет просто "input" без строки внутри, селениум сломается и не поймет что вытаскивать если укажете метод .text, я подобные ситуации решал с помощью execute_script, только через алерт, ибо просто превратить input в условный тэг <a> в котором будет строка нужная Вам, нет возможности.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/uwWJDBGlwCrT
Вытащили бы "Наименование (Ru)" с таким инпутом?

Comment: Кажется понял про что вы, спасибо!